# IOS phonegap streaming on plugin media

Tags: ios, cordova, media

[Media plugins](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/2634912296c1213e47cd79203807b2c41daa1c0e/doc/index.md)
I can't use streaming url on this plugin

```
function play()
{
   var audio = new Media("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9999/;stream.mp3");
   audio.play();
    }
play();
```

But if use mp3 url it work.

```
function play()
{
   var audio = new Media("http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3");
   audio.play();
}
play();
```

How can I fix or work around this problem? Thank you

Comment: try this `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9999/;`

Comment: @AtanuCSE i'm try it but not work